# does the Node member hold another Node or it's address in java

Tags: java, oop, pointers

When I have a member called Node in this class, as follows, does the member left hold another Node, or does it hold the address of another Node.

```
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

In C, there is no confusion because, you can separate them out as follows

```
typedef struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node left;
 struct node right; 
}Node;
```

and

```
typedef struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node* left;
 struct node* right; 
}Node;
```

Comment: A class in java is under the hood like a pointer that you can pass around.

Comment: There's no confusion if you understand that the language doesn't work with C `struct`s at all, they're just primitives or object references.

Comment: @Linus: An object is very different from a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [java](/questions/tagged/java), like in many other "modern" languages, there are no pointers. So, from the language's point of view, there's no way something can hold an *address* of an object. It holds the object.

But instead, there is the concept of a *reference type* which means passing around or assigning an object will indeed just create a new reference to the *same* object.

All classes in [java](/questions/tagged/java) are reference types. *Under the hood*, a reference is most probably implemented as a pointer, but the important thing about it is that the programmer doesn't have to (and shouldn't) care about this. All you have to know is that assigning or passing as a parameter will have reference semantics.

Btw, regarding your [c](/questions/tagged/c) example:

```
typedef struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node left;
 struct node right; 
}Node;
```

This will **not** work. `struct node` is an *incomplete type* at the time you declare your members `left` and `right`, so the compiler will refuse to compile here.

And think about it: What should the storage size of this `Node` be? The only valid answer would be: infinite. (or maybe twice infinite?).

Comment: A class is a reference type? I'd expect an "object name" to be a reference to the instance, but how can the class itself be a reference? Technically, a reference is a pointer under the hood. Other than a pointer, accessing its value will access to instance it references, so you can never get its own value, which would be the address of the object.

Comment: @Olaf, a class is a *reference type*, **not** a *reference* -- that's a difference. The reference itself of course represents an instance of that class. A reference is an opaque construct, although a pointer is of course the most *straight forward* implementation, it's just not important and shouldn't be considered at this level of abstraction. You could have a global "object registry" with the reference being some sort of hash key, it just doesn't matter to the programmer.

Comment: Hmm, I might be too deep in C and C++, where a `reference type` is different from a class. But in Python, it is the same: A name holds a reference (sure, the pointer is just an example, but that makes things easier to understand if you come from C) to an object, and a class is also an object, as much as a function.

Comment: @Olaf subtle language differences ;) Java is quite close to C# here. Whether you get reference semantics for objects depends on the type and a class is a *reference type* (which is different from C++, where you have to explicitly get a reference.) In C#, you can also define a *value type* with the keyword `struct` (otherwise no different from classes, but objects behave like C++ objects, being passed and assigned by value). Not sure whether Java has such a possibility.

Comment: Yes, but it is technically close to Python here, although Python has a higher abstraction level. If I understand it correct, in Java a "reference type" means objects of this type will be acessed through references instead of direct access like for simple types. Nomenclatural differences.

Comment: @Olaf yes, that's correct. (Or better yet: objects of these types will have *reference semantics* .. because if you never pass them around or assign them, it doesn't matter whether your object is indeed a reference)

Answer (score 2):

In java all non-primitive types are reference types. That means `Node` contains a reference to it's children, but the actual object is stored in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

> does the Node member hold another Node or it's address in java

You can see it as: The node is holding a variable which points to the reference of the other node(s).

So with this:

```
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
}
```

When you assign left and right to some other nodes, each node potentially carries a reference to 2 other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It holds address (reference) of other node variable as value.

Answer (score 0):

Members of a Java class are references (pointers) to objects when the type is another class

```
Node left;
Integer number;
```

but not when they are primitive types

```
int left;
```

in which case the actual value is held in the instance.

Also keep in mind that assignment when class instances are involved copies a reference

```
Node left;
Node right;
left = right;
```

Unless you use a copy constructor

```
Node left = new Node(right);
```